# turkey with beautiful browned skin that doesn't stick to the meat

Tags: turkey

I roast a turkey in a bag. The skin color is beautiful. But why doesn't  the skin stick to the turkey when I carve it.

Answer (score 7):

When it's in a bag, the steam produced during roasting is trapped.  A layer of steam occurs between the skin and the meat, separating the skin from the meat.

The same process happens when cooking without a bag, just more slowly, as the steam fills the entire oven - and then some of it escapes through vents or out the door seal.

Turkeys release a surprisingly large amount of liquid when cooked, compared to other poultry, so the skin separation is more pronounced than in chickens.

Comment: you are correct. Also consider the effect of direct heat on the outer part of the skin, contracting this part, thus almost squeezing it onto the meat.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try a light sear first and slowly move my knife in one motion per cut.